# How can I disable alt-tab on Fedora 25 (Wayland)

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts

I run a Fedora 25 distro
I am trying to disable `alt` `tab` in Fedora 25.
I've looked at

- gnome tweak: I do not see anything there
- `Setting>Keyboard` but this is not listed.

[image]

Comment: Note that you can also install several different shell extensions which change the behavior in various ways, if you'd like it to act differently rather than just being disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found it by usubg `dconf-editor`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To disable GNOME default `Alt+Tab` behavior

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
```

To restore `Alt+Tab`

```bash
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications
```